# Android custom camera action returns low resolution image

Tags: android

I have problem with the image I am getting from my camera activity. I did it following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath but for some reason I am getting low resolution images (On my phone 320x240, from emulated Pixel 640x480).

I create the Camera instance:

```
mCamera = CameraUtils(this).getCameraInstance()
```

then create the File:

```
public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(ConstantsStorage.CAMERA_PHOTO_DATETIME_FORMAT).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

then save the image to file:

```
        try {
            val fos = FileOutputStream(pictureFile)
            fos.write(data)
            fos.close()
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            Log.d(tag, "camera File not found: ${e.message}")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d(tag, "camera Error accessing file: ${e.message}")
        }
        intent.putExtra("file", pictureFile)
        intent.putExtra("idPhotoType", getPhotoTypeId())
        this.setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, intent)
        mCamera?.release()
        this.finish()
```

And then I read it from intent in onActivityResult.

I also tried to add some code to take FULL HD image after creating Camera instance, but it has no efect.

```
    mCamera = CameraUtils(this).getCameraInstance()
    val params = mCamera!!.parameters
    val sizes = params.supportedPictureSizes
    var w = 0
    var h = 0
    for (size in sizes) {
        if (size.width > w || size.height > h) {
            w = size.width
            h = size.height
        }

    }
    params.setPictureSize(1920, 1080)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var params = mCamera!!.getParameters()
                    var supportedSizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes()
                    sizePicture = supportedSizes.get(0)
                    params.setPictureSize(sizePicture.width, sizePicture.height)
                    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS)) {
                        params.focusMode = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                    }

                    mCamera!!.setParameters(params)
                    mCamera!!.startPreview()
                    mCamera!!.autoFocus(object : Camera.AutoFocusCallback {
                        override fun onAutoFocus(success: Boolean, camera: Camera?) {
                            try {
                                camera!!.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallbackRaw)
                            }
                            catch (ex:Exception)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Yeah, all I had to add was `mCamera!!.parameters = params`, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped happy coding ;)